# How to get full path of actual IXMLNode in Delphi?

Tags: xml, delphi, xpath

I've created a recursive function which adds all XML node names and values to a `TMemo`. But I need to have full XPath of each node. Now I can add a parent node's name, but not the full path. Something like this is needed:

**//document/itemlist/item/accessories/price : 158.54**

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S, ss: string;
  LNode: IDOMNode;
  Index: Integer;
        
  XMLPath:string;
  XMLDoc: IXMLDocument; 
  XMLSelect:IDomNodeSelect;
  MainNode, Data, Node: IXMLNode;
        
  procedure AddNodeValToMemo(NodeEl: IXMLNode);
  var
    j: Integer;
    TempNode: IXMLNode;
    S, ss: string;
  begin
    for j := 0 to NodeEl.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      TempNode := NodeEl.ChildNodes[j];
      if TempNode.IsTextElement then
      begin
        ss := TempNode.ParentNode.NodeName+'/'+TempNode.NodeName;
        S := TempNode.nodeValue;
        Memo1.Lines.Add(ss + ': ' + S);
        inc(Index);
        Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(Index);
      end;
      if TempNode.HasChildNodes then
        AddNodeValToMemo(TempNode);
    end;
  end;
        
begin
  XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
        
  XMLDoc.LoadFromFile(DIR + XMLFILE);
  XMLDoc.Active := True;
        
  XMLDoc.Options := XMLDoc.Options + [doNodeAutoIndent,doAutoPrefix];
  XMLDoc.Version := '1.0';
          
  Index:=0;
  MainNode := XMLDoc.documentElement;
  AddNodeValToMemo(MainNode);
        
  //     Form1.DomToTree(MainNode,nil);
  //     TreeView1.FullExpand;
        
  XMLDoc.Active := False;
end;
```

Comment: Since you are the one doing the recursion, you can just remember the path taken to the current node.

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep track of the current path to the node being added, and pass it along to the next iteration for each child, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S, ss: string;
  LNode: IDOMNode;
  Index: Integer;
        
  XMLPath: string;
  XMLDoc: IXMLDocument; 
  XMLSelect:IDomNodeSelect;
  MainNode, Data, Node: IXMLNode;
        
  procedure AddNodeValToMemo(const Path: string; NodeEl: IXMLNode);
  var
    j: Integer;
    TempNode: IXMLNode;
    S, ss:, nodePath string;
  begin
    nodePath := Path+'/'+NodeEl.NodeName;
    for j := 0 to NodeEl.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      TempNode := NodeEl.ChildNodes[j];
      if TempNode.IsTextElement then
      begin
        ss := nodePath+'/'+TempNode.NodeName;
        S := TempNode.NodeValue;
        Memo1.Lines.Add(ss + ': ' + S);
        inc(Index);
        Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Index);
      end;
      if TempNode.HasChildNodes then
        AddNodeValToMemo(nodePath, TempNode);
    end;
  end;
        
begin
  XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
        
  XMLDoc.LoadFromFile(DIR + XMLFILE);
  XMLDoc.Active := True;
        
  XMLDoc.Options := XMLDoc.Options + [doNodeAutoIndent,doAutoPrefix];
  XMLDoc.Version := '1.0';
          
  Index := 0;
  MainNode := XMLDoc.documentElement;
  AddNodeValToMemo('/', MainNode);
        
  //     Form1.DomToTree(MainNode,nil);
  //     TreeView1.FullExpand;
        
  XMLDoc.Active := False;
end;
```